# How to remove projects from the Recent Projects list in the Start Page?

Tags: configuration, preferences, netbeans-7.1

I started a new Enterprise Application project in Netbeans 7.1.1 and then later deleted the 3 projects ([project], [project]-war, [project]-ejb) from the projects window in the IDE, by right clicking them and selecting Delete, and also checking "[Delete all source files in folder on hard disk]", but it did not remove the projects from my Recent Projects in the Start Page.

I've searched through google, and most solutions are for netbeans 6.x and don't work for my version. These solutions say to find the file `./config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui.properties` from the install folder and remove them there. I have been unable to find this or a similar file, and haven't been able to do it from IDE itself either. How can I remove these Recent Projects? Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 22):

You should be able to find the `projectui.properties` file in:

Unix

```
 ~/.netbeans/<netbeans-version>/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui.propertie‌​s
```

Mac OS X [Absolute Path]

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/<netbeans-version>/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules‌​/projectui.propertie‌​s
```

Windows

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\<netbeans-version>\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui.propertie‌​s
```

Remember changes will be applied only on the specific NetBeans version for the specific user.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Do not forget to remove the lines corresponding to "recent project url" and "recent project icons".

Comment: Mac OS X path for NetBeans 8.1: `/Users/YourNameHere/Library/Application\ Support/NetBeans/8.1/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui.properties`

Comment: /Users/YourNameHere can be shortened to ~ So it's ~/Library/Application\ Support/NetBeans/8.1/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui.propertie‌​s

Answer (score 5):

In **windows 7** you could find the file `projectui.properties` in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules`

I also has found this file for my previous installation NetBeans IDE 7.0 in such path `C:\Users\[username]\Documents\.netbeans\7.0\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules`
But sure, this file is not actual.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the project name to get the context menu.  Select "Close
Project" and that will remove it from the displayed list of projects.

[click here for more details](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/How-to-delete-a-project-td2857520.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For me, closing Project from Project pannel does not remove my projects from Recent list.

Using snap installation for version 10.0, on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic beaver, you should go to 
`~/snap/netbeans/common/data/10.0/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules`

Remove content for "RecentProjects" keys :

- RecentProjectsDisplayNames
- RecentProjectsIcons
- recentProjectsURLs